# How to make useEffect() hook work the same for references to objects rather than objects themselves

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object reference from a react component (specifically swiperjs.com react component). I would like to react to changes in the objects properties (https://swiperjs.com/api/#methods), but useEffect() I find does not work in this case, with it being a reference only. Can anyone suggest what to do here?

```
  const [mySwiper, setmySwiper] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(mySwiper.isEnd)
  }, [mySwiper]);
```

Here is the setmySwiper logic, this is a

```
<Swiper>
...(other parameters)
onSwiper={(swiper) => setmySwiper(swiper)}
</Swiper>
```

And this is a console.log of mySwiper, it only appears on page refresh despite properties changing during component use:

```
Swiper {support: {…}, device: {…}, browser: {…}, eventsListeners: {…}, eventsAnyListeners: Array(0), …}
$: ƒ $(selector, context)
$el: Dom7 [div.swiper-container.swiper-container-initialized.swiper-container-vertical, __proto__: (...)]
$wrapperEl: Dom7 [div.swiper-wrapper, __proto__: (...)]
activeIndex: 0
allowClick: true
allowSlideNext: true
allowSlidePrev: true
allowTouchMove: true
animating: false
browser: {isEdge: false, isSafari: false, isWebView: false}
classNames: (2) ["swiper-container-initialized", "swiper-container-vertical"]
device: {ios: false, android: false}
el: div.swiper-container.swiper-container-initialized.swiper-container-vertical
eventsAnyListeners: []
eventsListeners: {_containerClasses: Array(1), _swiper: Array(1), init: Array(2), destroy: Array(2), resize: Array(1), …}
height: 535
imagesLoaded: 4
imagesToLoad: Dom7(4) [img, img, img, img, __proto__: (...)]
initialized: true
isBeginning: true
isEnd: false
isHorizontal: ƒ isHorizontal()
isVertical: ƒ isVertical()
loopCreate: ƒ ()
loopDestroy: ƒ ()
observer: {observers: Array(0), attach: ƒ, init: ƒ, destroy: ƒ}
onClick: ƒ ()
onTouchEnd: ƒ ()
onTouchMove: ƒ ()
onTouchStart: ƒ ()
originalParams: {init: true, direction: "vertical", touchEventsTarget: "container", initialSlide: 0, speed: 320, …}
params: {init: true, direction: "vertical", touchEventsTarget: "container", initialSlide: 0, speed: 320, …}
passedParams: {_emitClasses: false, on: {…}, init: true, direction: "vertical", touchEventsTarget: "container", …}
previousTranslate: 0
progress: -0
realIndex: 0
resize: {resizeHandler: ƒ, orientationChangeHandler: ƒ}
rtl: false
rtlTranslate: false
size: 535
slides: Dom7(4) [div.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active, div.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-next, div.swiper-slide, div.swiper-slide, __proto__: (...)]
slidesGrid: (4) [0, 535, 1070, 1605]
slidesSizesGrid: (4) [535, 535, 535, 535]
snapGrid: (4) [0, 535, 1070, 1605]
snapIndex: 0
support: {touch: false, pointerEvents: true, observer: true, passiveListener: true, gestures: false}
touchEvents: {start: "pointerdown", move: "pointermove", end: "pointerup"}
touchEventsData: {isTouched: undefined, isMoved: undefined, allowTouchCallbacks: undefined, touchStartTime: undefined, isScrolling: undefined, …}
touchEventsDesktop: {start: "pointerdown", move: "pointermove", end: "pointerup"}
touchEventsTouch: {start: "touchstart", move: "touchmove", end: "touchend", cancel: "touchcancel"}
touches: {startX: 0, startY: 0, currentX: 0, currentY: 0, diff: 0}
translate: -0
velocity: 0
virtualSize: 2140
width: 1903
wrapperEl: div.swiper-wrapper
wrongRTL: false
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1):

In class based components this is relatively straightforward - you would use `componentDidUpdate` to get a copy of the previous state and compare it with the new one manually. Functional components do away with the idea of lifecycle methods which can often get bloated and complicated, and instead ask that you tie specific data points together with a specific `useEffect` to achieve specific things.

You can target the individual properties of `mySwiper` in different `useEffect` instances, and those effects will only trigger when the indiviual properties change. For instance, this will only be triggered with changes to the `isEnd` property:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(mySwiper.isEnd);
}, [mySwiper.isEnd]);
```

However, if you really want to analyse the entire object in one go, you can use a `ref` to store the previous value of the state and compare against that. You'll have to check it exists for the first effect pass because refs always initialise as `undefined`. The bottom line is that if you want to take this approach, you are going to have to do your own object comparison - React isn't going to take care of it for you:

```
const [mySwiper, setMySwiper] = useState(0);
const prevSwiper = useRef(mySwiper);

useEffect(() => {
  if(prevSwiper.current) {
    // compare prevSwiper to mySwiper
  };
  prevSwiper.current = mySwiper;
}, [mySwiper]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did try the first solution earlier, and re-tried again with your exact code. But still the useEffect does not trigger. when isEnd turns true from false. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Ok, I think I've jumped ahead a bit. The useEffect in your original code sample should be logging regardless of whether you pass the whole object or just a property. Can you console log in the `onSlider` prop instead of setting state, just to make sure it's firing? If it is, then something has gone wrong with passing it the state setter, otherwise I'd suggest something's wrong with your `Swiper` config.

Comment: ok, console.log logs the object reference as per the output in the original post. If I use useEffect without any dependency, it only outputs the desired properties on console.log twice, once on page load and microsecond later on component initialisation, so first is undefined, then true, but no changes thereafter appear. I implemented a button which when pressed console .logs a property, and that property does change over time. Only the useEffect is not working.

Comment: Also, I implemented according to : https://swiperjs.com/react/, it does not comment on how to access the properties, only the events.

Comment: So the state is being set but the useEffect isn't triggering? All I can suggest is doing `(swiper) => setmySwiper({...swiper})` to create a new object but it shouldn't be necessary and the documentation doesn't mention it interacting with state hooks in this way. Otherwise, if there is any code in between the state and `Swiper` component, you should probably include that in the OP as well.

Comment: It is really strange, yes, I have verified the state is definately changing, but useEffect seems oblivious. I can work around it by setting another state after an event has happened, e.g. setmySwiperisEnd(mySwiper.isEnd). But this is not ideal as in the future I may find I need to react to a property that is not clearly linked with an event.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood how the library works - `onSlider` gets called when the slider is initialised, not when it is in use, so the state is and only should be set once. I'm not sure how you would go about watching the state object itself. I will stop suggesting things as I clearly don't know enough about it, but here is a [react demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-id-swiper-update-problem-fix-swiperjs-next-jgokc?file=/src/App.tsx:2462-2473) I found which might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions that link was still useful

Answer (score 0):

`useRef` as `this.ref = ...` doesn’t notify you when its content changes, if you are using hooks you could change your `useRef` to a `useCallback` and that would notify you. If that doesn't work for you try using `useLayoutEffect`

Comment: Hi, can you provide an example and if it works I will accept the answer

Comment: Please share the setmySwiper logic so I can write an example

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node